# extracting lists from list of lists based on character of index

Tags: python, list, bioinformatics

I have a list of lists, called dregeiSNPs:

```
[['ACmerged_contig_24664', '378', '.', 'T', 'A', '7.30814', '.', 'DP=1;SGB=-0.379885;MQ0F=0;AC=2;AN=2;DP4=0,0,0,1;MQ=36', 'GT:PL', '1/1:36,3,0'],
 ['ACmerged_contig_24664', '379', '.', 'G', 'A', '4.38466', '.', 'DP=1;SGB=-0.379885;MQ0F=0;AC=2;AN=2;DP4=0,0,0,1;MQ=36', 'GT:PL', '1/1:32,3,0'],
 ['ACmerged_contig_24664', '383', '.', 'G', 'A', '7.30814', '.', 'DP=1;SGB=-0.379885;MQ0F=0;AC=2;AN=2;DP4=0,0,0,1;MQ=36', 'GT:PL', '1/1:36,3,0']]
```

I am trying to put the lists within this into different lists, depending on the letters in `list[3]` and `list[4]`. If the characters in `list[3]` and `list[4]` are both 'T' or 'C', or both 'A' or 'G', I want these lines to go into one list `dregeiTransitions`, if otherwise I want the lines to go into `dregeiTransversions`.

I will use this code for a larger dataset in the end.

I have written this code:

```
dregeiTransitions = []
dregeiTransversions = []
for (line, list) in enumerate(dregeiSNPs):
    if list[3] == 'T' or 'C' and list[4] == 'T' or 'C':
        dregeiTransitions.append()
    if list[3] == 'A' or 'G' and list[4] == 'A' or 'G':
        dregeiTransitions.append()
    else:
        dregeiTransversions.append()
```

But I get this error:

```
  File "project1.py", line 42, in <module>
    dregeiTransitions.append()
TypeError: append() takes exactly one argument (0 given)
```

Can someone explain why this happens? Surely I should not be reaching an `.append` statement unless the above `if` or `else` criteria are fulfilled?

Comment: Your `list[3] == 'T' or 'C' and list[4] == 'T' or 'C'` won't work -- use `(list[3] == 'T' or list[3] == 'C') and (list[4] == 'T' or list[4] == 'C')`, or alternatively `list[3] in ['T', 'C'] and list[4] in ['T', 'C']`. Also avoid using `list` as a variable name - it is a [built in function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html)

Comment: Out of curiosity, in practice, how many of these SNPs will you be dealing with in your full data set, and how often? Depending on the size of the data, in practice you will want to use Numpy or possibly Pandas. I can show you a more efficient solution if you think it's necessary. If it's just small lists like your example it's probably not such a big deal though.

Comment: @Iguananaut My final files are a lot larger (~30k SNPs), but this is part of an assignment for a class, and we are still at a very basic level, so I don't really want to start with bigger files and more advanced code yet. Thanks though!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to tell it what to append. Change the appends to: `dregeiTransitions.append(list)` and it should work.